# How to AutoFill second TextBox according to first TextBox with the corresponding data in the DataBase

Tags: c#, database, winforms, autocomplete, relationship

In my winform, there's a datatable with `2 column, 1st one is studentname & 2nd column is StudentAverage`.
First txtbx is autosuggest(studentname).
How to make the second txtbx automaticaly fill according to 1st txtbx (2nd txtbx fill with the corresponding record of second column (studentsavrage)?

this is for the 1st txtbx; shows StudentNames

```
private void txtbxName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            string StrCmd = "SELECT * FROM School";
            string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\School_Database.accdb";
            OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
            MyConn.Open();
            OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn); ;
            OleDbDataReader ObjReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (ObjReader != null)
        {
            while (ObjReader.Read())
                namesCollection.Add(ObjReader["StudentName"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
        }
            ObjReader.Close();
            MyConn.Close();
            txtbxName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            txtbxName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            txtbxName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;         
    }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are developing with WinForms.

First out: since a where clause is missing from your query you are not filtering while user inputs text. You should move AutoCompleteStrinCollection fetching in another place if you don't want that.

Your problem: the simplier way here is to manually update the second textbox in your `txtbxName_TextChanged` method.

```
private void txtbxName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string StrCmd = String.Format( "SELECT AGE FROM School WHERE name '{0', txtbox1.Text");
     //perform query as you already do and read result
     textbox2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
}
```

P.S: in real world things are not done the way you are doing under many many aspects